# How can I clean mold from the defrost drain on my refrigerator?

Tags: water, leak, ice, freezer

I own a Blomberg Refrigerator with Ice maker model number K70520NLU.
Water is leaking onto the floor from the freezer. The coils keep freezing every two weeks. I need to empty the contents, take off the back cover and unfreeze the ice buildup along the coils with a hair dryer. Doing this does not solve my problem because the ice buildup and water leaks start again within 7-10 after unfreezing the ice buildup. Upon inspecting the back portion of the freezer, I noticed that there is a lot of black buildup in the water hose. I suspect this is what is causing the issues, but I am not sure. How can this part be cleaned or should it be replaced? What is the purpose of this part and can this be the reason I am having the problem? The ice maker works and produces ice. Any info is greatly appreciated. I've owned this fridge for the past 7 years.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two issues.

There should be a drip pan over the compressor that is used to evaporate access water. Check if it is clogged.

Second issue:

The freezer has a built-in timer that defrosts the coils about every 7 hours. That function might not be working. It is a electric function.

How to clean the part. Remove it and use bottle brush.

Golden rule: If they have assembled it, you can disassemble unless it is glued.

Comment: To add, often the defroster has a little metal tab attached to the heater element; the tab is supposed to stick down into the defrost drain tube to prevent the drain tube from icing up.  Sometimes, the tab is simply not designed properly so that it actually goes far enough into the tube, or gets moved out of position.  When this happens, the drain tube can get blocked with ice, and the melted defrost overflows into the refrigerator cabinet.